# Passing a function as parameter in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli, interop, native, mixed-mode

I am wrapping a c++ library to CLI so it can run on c#.

This is my function in c++ library :

```
void setCallback(void (*pFunc)(void * pParam), void * pParam);
```

Here is the example :

```
    void callbackHandler(int iNum )
    {
        cout<<"Callback : "<< iNum <<endl;
    }

    myObj.setCallback(callbackHandler,3);
```

How to convert to CLI function ?
How to pass a c# function to the setCallback (c++) function ?

Comment: You need to make a `delegate` type, and an unmanaged structure that contains a `gcroot<ThatDelegateType^>`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at4fb09f(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 1):

The [question "Passing C++/CLI Class Method as C function pointer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184568/passing-c-cli-class-method-as-c-function-pointer) should provide also a solution for your problem.

(Beside that please check your example: I think "myObj.setCallback(callbackHandler,3);" will not compile, because the signature of setCallback is `void setCallback(void (*pFunc)(void * pParam), void * pParam);` and NOT `void setCallback(void (*pFunc)(int * pParam), int param);`)